# Webpack definePlugin not setting/reading node_env variable

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-redux

I'm having real issues injecting the node_env var into my code through Webpack's definePlugin and after reading numerous posts nothing seems to work. I have a feeling I'm missing something...

So my production webpack config is -

```
// Config
import path from 'path';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import config from './config';


/**
 * Webpack config for compiling the
 * React/Redux/ES6 scripts.
 *
 * ENV = production
 *
 * @type {Object}
 */
module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, '../', config.assets.scripts.src_dir, config.assets.scripts.entry),
    devtool: false,
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, config.assets.scripts.dist_dir),
        filename: config.assets.scripts.dist_min
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /.js?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015,presets[]=stage-0',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: 'json-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
            }
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({})
    ]
};
```

I've tried setting alias's for react, react-dom and react-redux with absolutely no avail, React still warns me i'm using a minified version outside of node_env=production (Also redux still throws me this error).

FYI, i'm using webpack version 2.2.1.

Is it something to do with the babel-loader conflicting in some way? If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try changing your `DefinePlugin` for `NODE_ENV` to this one -

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env.NODE_ENV' : JSON.stringify('production')
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        minimize : true,
        compress : {
            warnings : false
        }
    })
]
```

Comment: This did actually work (or at least I think it did as it seems to have cleared the error).

Do you have any knowledge on why you must specific the object property like that? Is it a bug with Webpack?

Thanks

Comment: @liamta I think for more clarification you should read this thread https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/868
And if it did work for you then please accept the answer.
thanks