# webpack warning - WARNING in DefinePlugin Conflicting values for 'process.env.NODE_ENV'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, babeljs

I'm getting the warning in the title when I try to run development mode. This script used to work fine for an earlier website but now I always get this warning.

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development --watch",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.12",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.13",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "webpack": "^5.27.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.13.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"
  }
}
```

And my webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./static/frontend"),
    filename: "[name].js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": {
        // This has effect on the react lib size
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("production"),
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```

I've searched around everywhere but couldn't find anything similar to this warning.

Comment: did you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43086635/7574023)?

Answer (score 32):

try changing

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": {
        // This has effect on the react lib size
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("production"),
      },
    }),
```

to

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env.NODE_ENV' : JSON.stringify('production')
    })
]
```

Answer (score 19):

You are saying you "try to run development mode".
According to your `package.json` that means running:

`webpack --mode development --watch` (NOTE: v4 syntax)

1. The [`mode` parameter](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/) is the mode to be used when webpack is running, meaning during "*build time*" (or "compile time").
2. The `DefinePlugin` checks that variable when you try to define it for your "*run time*" (which is different from "*build time*"), and thus warns you if the two are different ([code here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/v5.41.0/lib/DefinePlugin.js#L574)).

### Solution

Make sure, [`mode`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/) in your webpack.config object (or in the CLI command, which overrides it in the config object) is the same as the one you pass to the `DefinePlugin`.

### How to access webpack CLI parameters in `webpack.config.js`?

If you want to be able to provide the `mode` parameter from CLI or a `package.json` script, and still have the `DefinePlugin` not give a warning (meaning you get that value from the CLI and plug that into the `DefinePlugin`), do this:

Change the contents of your `webpack.config.js` from your `module.exports = { mode: ..., rules: ... };` (or `export default { ... }`) config `object` to a `function` as shown below.
This function works exactly the same (you `return` the final config object), but allows reading environment variables from the first parameter `env`, as well as [webpack CLI options](https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/#options) from the second argument `argv`:

```js
module.exports = (env, argv) => {
  // `mode` is `'XX'` if you ran webpack like so: `webpack watch --mode XX` (v5 syntax)
  const mode = argv.mode || 'development'; // dev mode by default

  // ...

  return {
    mode,   // this is optional, since webpack already knows the `mode` from the CLI parameter
    // ...
    plugins: [
      // ...
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(mode)
      })
    ]
    // ...
  };
};
```

**PS**: You are using Webpack@4. If you used Webpack@5, you would have to change

`webpack --mode development --watch`

to

`webpack watch --mode development`.

**PPS**: Always prefer `'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('X')` over  `'process.env': JSON.stringify({ NODE_ENV: 'X' })`, since the former safely replaces all occurrences of `process.env.NODE_ENV` in your code with `"X"`, while the latter replaces any occurrence of `process.env` with `{ "NODE_ENV": "X" }`. That in turn is likely going to mess up other environment variables. Example: `process.env.Y` will become `({ "NODE_ENV": "X" }).Y` which is `undefined`.

Comment: Alternatively to changing the mode, you can change `optimization.nodeEnv` to false to prevent the mode from setting NODE_ENV if you already define it yourself via DefinePlugin.

Comment: Thanks @mbillard, for pointing out nodeEnv to false as it helps me to resolve the definePlugin Process.Env conflict issue.

Answer (score 12):

Thanks for helping everyone, very much appreciated!

I ended up replacing "production" with "development" in the following snippet of the webpack.config:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": {
        // This has effect on the react lib size
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("development"),
      },
    }),
  ]
```

It got rid of the warning but I'm wondering what impact this has.

Comment: Webpack has an algorithm to get rid of unreachable code. So in React there is plenty of `if process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"` (just an example) that should be removed when building for other env. You should keep `production` as it makes your bundle much lighter

Comment: @ser does that mean we should ignore the warning?

Answer (score 6):

This error means that you tried to reassign `process.env.NODE_ENV` in `DefinePlugin` call with the value different from it has before.

You can set it implicitly by adding `mode` option to config, or adding `nodeEnv` key to `optimization`. Or just set the environment variable before you run webpack.

And it looks like that is your case. You set `NODE_ENV=development` somewhere, ran webpack, and then you are trying to reassign it to `production`.

Check how do you run webpack and NODE_ENV environment value.

Answer (score 0):

```
The value in  NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("this_value_here") 
should match the value inside package.json "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development --watch",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
```

If you are running `"npm run dev"`, keep the `JSON.stringify("development")`, if you are running `"npm run build"` ,change it to `JSON.stringify("production")`.
Basically, match it to the type of mode you are running.

Answer (score 0):

Try next thing:

**1) In your package.json**

```
"scripts": {
  "start": ...
  "lint": ...
  "serve": "NODE_ENV=production webpack serve",
}
```

**2) In your console:**

```
npm run serve
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": {
        // This has effect on the react lib size
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("production"),
      },
    }),
```

to

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            "process.env": {
                // This has effect on the react lib size
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("development"),
            },
        })
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is a duplicate of another answer