# Conflicting values for 'process.env' with Webpack Encore and Dotenv

Tags: symfony, webpack, dotenv, webpack-encore

I'm using Webpack Encore with [Dotenv-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack) and I'm getting this error:

> Failed to compile.
>
> DefinePlugin
>
> Conflicting values for 'process.env'

My webpack.config.js:

```
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack')
const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore')

if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
  Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev')
}

Encore
  // ...
  .addPlugin(new Dotenv({
    path: './.env.local'
  }))

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Versions used:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^1.2.0",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^7.0.2",
}
```

I've found [similar issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66772358/webpack-warning-warning-in-defineplugin-conflicting-values-for-process-env-no), but I don't really understand the solution and therefor not able to use this solution with Symfony Encore.

What's the cause of this issue and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue giving warnings on compile and this was fixed by adding the `ignoreStub` option to `true`.

```
.addPlugin(new Dotenv({
    ignoreStub: true,
}))
```

This was introduced with version 7.0.0 of `dotenv-webpack`.

https://github.com/mrsteele/dotenv-webpack/releases/tag/v7.0.0

Comment: This Worked, thanks.

Comment: More explanations at https://github.com/mrsteele/dotenv-webpack?tab=readme-ov-file#processenv-stubbing--replacing