# NODE_ENV and mode in webpack 5

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

In webpack 4, I was able to specify different values for `NODE_ENV` and webpack `mode`.  In my application, I am using `NODE_ENV` to indicate the environment with possible values of `local`, `development`, `qa`, `staging`, and `production`. Separately, I was setting `mode` in webpack to control optimizing my bundle.  If my environment was `staging` or `production`, I would set the webpack `mode` to `production`, else it would use `development`.

In webpack 5, this does not seem possible.  When I simply try to upgrade webpack from 4 to 5 and run my application, I get the following warning:

[image]

`"local"' !== '"development"`

My DefinePlugin is defined as follows:

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      NODE_ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV ?? '',
      ...variablesFromEnvironmentJsonConfig
    }
  }),
  ...
]
```

And I define `mode` in the config as follows:

```
mode: shouldOptimizeBundle ? 'production' : 'development',
```

So it appears webpack 5 has a problem when `NODE_ENV` does not equal `mode`.  Webpack 5's [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/) says the supported values for `mode` are `development`, `production`, and `none`.  Then, confusingly, it says *"If mode is not provided via configuration or CLI, CLI will use any valid NODE_ENV value for mode."*

Ideally, I'd be able to continue doing what I do in webpack 4 which is have optimization and environment not be dependent of each other. In webpack 5, is it possible to have `NODE_ENV` be different than `mode`?

Comment: Can you show the code for `DefinePlugin`? And this is just a warning isn't it? It still compiles fine?

Comment: @ChrisHamilton `DefinePlugin` code added. It is just a warning and my app compiles successfully. One concern is that it's not actually using the mode and NODE_ENV I'm setting because it wants them to be the same. I'm checking that now.

Comment: It appears to be using what I set. So perhaps it's just a warning, but I don't understand why it's needed at all since it implies they should be the same.

Comment: Have you looked at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66772358/webpack-warning-warning-in-defineplugin-conflicting-values-for-process-env-no

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the config you want is `optimization.nodeEnv`.

From the docs: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimizationnodeenv

> **optimization.nodeEnv**
>
> boolean = false string
>
> Tells webpack to set process.env.NODE_ENV to a given string value.
>
> optimization.nodeEnv uses DefinePlugin unless set to false.
>
> optimization.nodeEnv defaults to mode if set, else falls back to 'production'.
>
> Possible values:
>
> any string: the value to set process.env.NODE_ENV to.
>
> false: do not modify/set the value of process.env.NODE_ENV.
>
> **webpack.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  //...
  optimization: {
    nodeEnv: 'production',
  },
};
```

> Tip
>
> When mode is set to 'none', optimization.nodeEnv defaults to false.

This is probably what causes the warning:

> optimization.nodeEnv defaults to mode if set, else falls back to 'production'.

I believe setting this config to `false` will eliminate the warning, although the description seems to have conflicting statements.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `NODE_ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV ?? ''` and instead pass `--mode=production` or `--mode=development` to Webpack.

In Webpack 5, the `mode` setting replaces manually defining `NODE_ENV` as you are doing, which is why it calls it complains about conflicting values.

> If not set, webpack sets production as the default value for mode.

You can also specify these in the config, at the top level.

```js
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
};
```

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/

---

If you have any issues with that solution I'll be happy to help.

Comment: As I mentioned, I need then to be different values.

Comment: then = them....

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to change the behavior according to the `mode` variable inside the webpack.config.js. In that case, you have to export a function instead of an object and use the second parameter(`argv` in the example below):

```js
var config = {
  entry: './app.js',
  //...
};

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
  if (argv.mode === 'development') {
    config.devtool = 'source-map';
  }

  if (argv.mode === 'production') {
    //...
  }

  return config;
};
```

[Source](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/).